# Ejecutar JS en HTML con $

Tags: javascript, html, html5, body

Quiero ejecutar Javascript en una etiqueta HTML mediante ${} sin usar scripts.

Doy un ejemplo:

`<p>resultado: ${5+5}</p>`

`<h1>nota: ${notafinal}</h1>`

Y que cuando se cargue la página diga 10 y la nota final. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso en Javascript?

Comment: Te contradices: **sin usar scripts** y luego preguntas: **¿Cómo puedo hacer eso en Javascript?** `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Es posible que lo que estés buscando sea sobre nodejs o una forma especial de strings en javascript. Aclara tu pregunta.

Comment: Dije eso por si me respondía con <p>${5+5}</p> <script>p.textContent = 10</script> o algo parecido @Mauricio Contreras

Comment: Toma en cuenta que `${ }` no es una sintáxis de HTML, por lo tanto, a menos que uses un motor de plantillas o insertes el valor que quieres directamente usando JS, no puedes mezclar esa sintáxis que muestras.

Answer (score 0):

Según como yo lo veo y lo entiendo, lo que deseas es insertar un valor sobre un elemento `HTML` usando Javascript.

Existen muchas formas de hacerlo, por ejemplo, podrías usar un elemento tipo `span` de `HTML` con un atributo `id` con el cual puedas identificarlo.

Se podría ver así:

```js
let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
let nota = document.getElementById('nota');

resultado.innerText = 5 + 5;
nota.innerText = 20;
```

```html
<p>resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>

<h1>nota: <span id="nota"></span></h1>
```

Falta que establezcas cómo calculas el resultado y la nota final, pero la idea es esa, usar la propiedad [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) para establecer el valor del elemento `<span>` que capturas usando su atributo `id`.

La sisntaxis que muestras en tu pregunta: `${ }` no es interpretada por el navegador como lo hace el motor de Javascript. Existen motores de plantillas que usan sintaxis especiales para incrustar valores de esta forma, pero esto no es parte de la especificación `HTML`, y estos motores usan JS para lograr su cometido. Tal como te he mostrado en esta respuesta.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.